# google compute startup script starting postgresql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a startup script set by an instance template that initializes the server for google compute.  After installing postgres, I manually call for it to start using :

/etc/init.d/postgresql start

This completes successfully, but the server is not listening on 5432 when run by the startup script (postgres isn't started, although that service start call completes successfully).  After startup completes, and I log in, I can do it successfully.  Anyone know why that won't work within the startup script ?  I need to load up data during startup so I need to startup postgres during initialization.

Comment: Are you using CloudSQL for PostgreSQL or installing PostgreSQL on top of your GCE VM, or are you just trying to connect to a PostgreSQL server only? Also, can you share the startup script that you been using and the output of [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole)?

Comment: Ok so I think I figured it out.  Was using an older debian that I thought was stable but was apparently a bit too old.  Using a newer image in my template, postgres came up as expected.  Will close this now.

Comment: Hi aao, can you post your solution as an answer to this question which would be helpful for the community and also will have better visibility to someone who has a similar issue in future?

Answer (score 1):

I Solved using newer debian image

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you (installing postgresql in GCE startup-script results in the package being installed, but the server is not running), and I think I figured out the root cause.

Normally, the postgresql-11 package is supposed to start the PostgreSQL server after installation. Here is a snippet from its postinst script:

```
if [ "$1" = configure ]; then
    . /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions

    configure_version $VERSION "$2"
fi
```

Taking a look at `/usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions`, we see:

```
configure_version() {
    ...
    # reload systemd to let the generator pick up the new unit
    if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
        systemctl daemon-reload
    fi
    invoke-rc.d postgresql start $VERSION # systemd: argument ignored, starts all versions
}
```

My debian installation comes with init-system-helpers version "1.56+nmu1", which contains [this bit of code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/init-system-helpers/-/blob/debian/1.56/script/invoke-rc.d#L507-514) in invoke-rc.d:

```
# avoid deadlocks during bootup and shutdown from units/hooks
# which call "invoke-rc.d service reload" and similar, since
# the synchronous wait plus systemd's normal behaviour of
# transactionally processing all dependencies first easily
# causes dependency loops
if ! systemctl --quiet is-active multi-user.target; then
  sctl_args="--job-mode=ignore-dependencies"
fi
case $saction in
  start|restart|try-restart)
      [ "$_state" != "LoadState=masked" ] || exit 0
      systemctl $sctl_args "${saction}" "${UNIT}" && exit 0
      ;;
```

The debian postgresql-11 package makes use of templated systemd units. The main one is called `postgresql.service` but this is a dummy service that doesn't actually do anything. The PostgreSQL server is actually started by a templated unit named `postgresql@11-main` which is usually started alongside the main service because it has `ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service`.

Note that when this issue occurs, the main unit is started but the templated one is not:

```
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2021-04-02 05:40:48 UTC; 32min ago
 Main PID: 1663 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4665)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Apr 02 05:40:48 hubnext-west-r21r systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Apr 02 05:40:48 hubnext-west-r21r systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.

$ sudo systemctl status postgresql@11-main
● postgresql@11-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

That's because when `--job-mode=ignore-dependencies` is specified, this link is ignored.

The GcE startup script runs as a systemd unit, which starts before multi-user.target is up:

```
$ find /etc/systemd | grep startup
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/google-startup-scripts.service
```

Therefore, invoke-rc.d notices that `systemctl --quiet is-active multi-user.target` is false and adds `--job-mode=ignore-dependencies`, which results in the PostgreSQL server not starting.

One possible workaround is explicitly running `systemd start postgresql@11-main.service` from your startup script after installing postgres.

---

By the way, I noticed that [a recent commit](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/init-system-helpers/-/commit/3988cf70533b9a826727a26ce6dce91755a0fb22) (Nov 2020) changed this invoke-rc.d behavior so that it no longer uses `--job-mode=ignore-dependencies`. That would help avoid this issue.